# Locating the external scripts

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I thought it is good practice to put the loading of scripts at the bottom of the page.  Hence, I have the scripts (jquery01.5.1.min.js) located at the bottom of the layout file.

However, the moment I started using Ajax, eg in a WebGrid, it inserted a:

```
<script type="text/javascript">if (typeof(jQuery)=='undefined') alert("A jQuery script reference is required in order to enable Ajax support in the \"WebGrid\" helper.");</script>
```

somwhere at the <TABLE> tag.  This spoils the show.

Is there any way to overcome this and still have the scripts loaded at the end of the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always add a quick header file to take the `jQuery` variable and make sure it is initialized. jQuery should be able to go back through then and load itself after that code is hit. AKA

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var jQuery = {};
</script>
```